# What am I doing wrong on using angular-slick-carousel? It doesn't work for me

Tags: onsen-ui, slick.js

I need a carousel on a hybrid app using onsen ui, angular and slick carousel.
I've already added this:

```html
<script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-slick/dist/slick.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

<slick dots="true" infinite="false" speed="300" slides-to-show="5" touch-move="false" slides-to-scroll="1">
      <div class="oneConsultor"><img src="img/atendimento/atm1.jpg"></div>
      <div class="oneConsultor"><img src="img/atendimento/atm2.jpg"></div>
      <div class="oneConsultor"><img src="img/atendimento/atm3.jpg"></div>
      <div class="oneConsultor"><img src="img/atendimento/atm1.jpg"></div>
      <div class="oneConsultor"><img src="img/atendimento/atm2.jpg"></div>
      <div class="oneConsultor"><img src="img/atendimento/atm3.jpg"></div>
    </slick>
```

and it doesnt't work for me :(

Comment: is actually image found on the url?

Comment: Yes, even with text, it doesn't slides

Comment: Could it be problems because I am using onsen-ui?

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.